# Dummy encoding the categorical variables using the changed version of OneHotEncoder

Tags: python, categorical-data, dummy-variables, one-hot-encoding, categorical-encoding

This is my code, I was trying to dummy encode the first column of X using OneHotEncoder but it was showing error and the documentation page of OneHotEncoder says that it has been changed and I wasn't able to figure out how I can do it using the changed version. the data type of X is numpy.ndarray.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
onehotencoder=OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
X[:, 0]=onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float, this is the error, the column has string as entries

Comment: Duplicate of https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/56831/55122

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using

```
X = pd.get_dummies(X)
```

?

Otherwise make sure that your X is either a 2D Array or a dataframe for OneHotEncoding to work.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways. For the just the first colum, this should work:

```py
pd.get_dummies(X.iloc[:,0])
```

If you want to explore better ways to encode features you can always use 
https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/index.html

It has the following parameter that should allow you to encode the columns that you want:

> cols: list
>   a list of columns to encode, if None, all string columns will be encoded.