# How do i get dummies for this dataset

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, dataset, encoding

I am using an udemy course for MachineLearning and I am trying to form a dummy for my variable the column is Country

I want to change to   France   Germany   Spain

```
- France                             1        0       0
- Spain                              0        0       1
- Germany                            0        1       0  etc
```

I tried this but I got this error

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_values = [0])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-9-f7654080cf6a>", line 4, in <module>
    onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_values = [0])

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_values'
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error says: there is no `categorical_values` parameter for `OneHotEncoder`.  It was removed at the same time that `OneHotEncoder` was extended to deal with strings directly, and you may want to use `ColumnTransformer` for selecting out the categorical column(s).  For example, https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/57383/55122

Answer (score 0):

Its easier to perform this by method get_dummies:

```
X_enc = pd.get_dummies(X)
```

Reference:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html

Answer (score 0):

```
col = []
for c in df.columns:
    if df[c].dtypes=='object':
        col.append(c)

df_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df , columns=col, drop_first=True) ## get dummies part
```

It is a good practice to use the `drop_first` parameter as it would avoid the model getting overfitted.